# Setting up Lubuntu partitions with RAID 5

Tags: linux, software-raid

This might be a silly question, but I'm about to set up a home backup/media server with 4x3TB drives, running Lubuntu on a Dell PowerEdge T20.  It will have periodic large writes at off hours, and frequent reading.  I'd like to set it up using RAID 5, giving me 9 TB of storage, but I understand I have to have a separate volume for the OS, given that it can't run with RAID 5.  I only have 4 bays, so having a separate small drive for the OS isn't an option.

I assume that to maximize space, I need to distribute the needed storage for OS and swap evenly across all four drives.  I assume I want to have something on the order of 5 GB or so for the OS and somewhere around 8 GB for swap.

I understand that the OS will only run on either RAID 1 or on a single drive.  So I could either have a 4x5 GB RAID 1 array for the OS, and a 4x2 GB RAID 0 array for swap, or just a single 5GB for the OS, and 3x5 GB RAID 0 for swap.  RAID 1 doesn't feel super necessary for the OS, I can always just reinstall it in the event of a disk failure, but on the other hand, it's not like I'm hurting for storage space so it hardly seems to matter.

Is my understanding correct? Are there any important factors I need to consider here that I haven't mentioned, that would mean I shouldn't use one or either of these configurations? Also, it looks like the machine uses a hardware Intel RAID controller. Is there any reason to favor one over the other, hardware vs. letting the OS manage it?

Comment: Well if it is a hardware raid as you mention towards the end then your OS can be on it, if it is a software one then it can't. You should be fine as you said it has an Intel RAID controller

Comment: ah!  So I'll just set it up as a single RAID 5 array, handled in BIOS I assume?  Would it be wise to still have a separate RAID 0 array for swap, given the performance boost?  Thanks for your comment, can you make it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well it depends on how old your raid controller is. I talked to the maker of a hardware raid controller once and he explained it to me that older RAID 5 setups would use the one drive as a swap like what I am sure you have seen in diagrams but that newer RAID 5's put the swap on all the drives. This used to not be very efficient but with the advancement in drives and read / write speeds apparently it can now be done. I may be wrong on this as it is what I heard but makes sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your OS on a RAID 5 setup when using a hardware RAID. The raid controller and hard drives can be thought of as their own system which isn't tied to the OS or computer they are attached to. Your computer just has the ability to read and write to this system. This makes it possible to put an OS on it. Where the OS goes is really determined by your raid card and since it is a raid, that means your OS is actually on all of the drives.

If you had a software RAID then you could not put the OS on the raid itself. This is because for that kind of system, in order for the raid to work it requires the OS. The OS becomes a part of the required system to work. You could have an OS accessing the OS + raid system though.

Comment: Followup: It *seems* like it has a hardware RAID setup, but I wasn't able to get it to work on Lubuntu.  I could go into the bios of my PowerEdge T20 and set up one big RAID volume, but when I was installing the OS, it didn't recognize that.  It just saw the four unused drives.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you format the raid after setting it up?